# Does removing an Item in Plaid destroy the access_token?

Tags: plaid

If an item is removed using the remove endpoint, does that make the access_token not valid anymore? is that effectively the same as destroying the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically yes.

As stated in [Plaid docs](https://plaid.com/docs/#remove-an-item) :

> The /item/remove endpoint allows you to remove an Item. Once removed, the access_token associated with the Item is no longer valid and cannot be used to access any data that was associated with the Item.